# Making part of the fragment transparent

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a tutorial for my app, in which an overlay fragment should be displayed over the already viewed activity, for which i can provide some info. The fragment I'm trying to create looks like the attached image, that is; make the rectangular part transparent to be able to see what's behind the fragment and also show some info inside the grey-ish part of the fragment.

Any idea how can i make something like in the xml file for the overlay fragment?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is that a showcase fragment that you want to implement? Just to illustrate what I mean, is it something looking like what this library provides: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6713 ?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, yes that's what exactly i'm looking for. Sorry i didn't know the specific name for it. Do you have any info on creating a custom showcase fragment?